# Html form submit Check string

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Need to setup an HTML Form, if entered value match given value then ACTION1 else ACTION2 
i have 2 pages m1.htm & m2.htm, `my value is 12345`, if form submit 12345 open `m1.htm` if wrong open `m2.htm`.

```
<form name="input" action="m1.htm" method="post">
<input type="text" name="q"><input type='submit' value='Search'/>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    <form name="input" action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="q">
         <input type='submit' value='Search' id='search'/>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").click(function(){
        if($("input[name='q']").val() == 12345){
             document.forms[0].action="m1.html";
             document.forms[0].submit();
            return true;
        }else{
            document.forms[0].action="m2.html";
            document.forms[0].submit();
            return true;
        }
       });
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6ftjhm88/

Answer (score 0):

You should try to do it yourself first then ask the question not just ask for the code.

Code Snippet:

```
<form name="input" action="m1.htm" method="post">
<input type="text" name="q"><input type='submit' value='Search' id='submit'/>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#submit').on('click',  function(e)
  {
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();

    if($('input[type="text"][name="q"]').val() == "")
    {
        alert('Please Enter a Value!');
        return false;

    }else if($('input[type="text"][name="q"]').val() == "12345")
    {
         window.location.href = 'm1.htm';

    }else {
         window.location.href = 'm2.htm';
    }

  });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use **location.replace()**  function to load your html file according to your condition

i.e

```
if(value=12345)
 location.replace('/m1.htm')
 else
 location.replace('/m2.html')
```